# Use pack parameter in template vector & Lambda - c++

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, variadic-templates

I am trying variadic template pack inside lambda function with vector.
Learning the *c++ programming langage* book, it's said "If you need to capture a variadic template argument, use ..." (with a simple example).

I am not able to compile it, my aim is just to be able to print the variadic type inside my lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template<typename... vectType>
void printAllElements(vector<vectType...>& nbList, ostream& output, int nbToTest){
  for_each(begin(nbList),end(nbList),
    [&vectType...](vectType... x){
      vectType... v;
      output << x << endl;
      output << typeid(v).name() << endl;
    }
  );
}

int main() {
  vector<int> myVect {10,20,156,236};
  printAllElements(myVect,cout, 4);
}
```

StackTrace:

```
learnC++/main.cpp:10:7: error: 'vectType' in capture list does not name a variable
    [&vectType...](vectType... x){
      ^
learnC++/main.cpp:11:15: error: only function and template parameters can be parameter packs
      vectType... v;
              ^
learnC++/main.cpp:12:7: error: variable 'output' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified
      output << x << endl;
```

Regards

**Update 1:**

Ok so I update this question to add the two code of Stroustrup  I concataned with his advices.

**Lambda & Vector**

```
Void print_modulo(const vector<int>& v, ostream& os, int m){
  for_each(begin(b),end(v),
  [&os,m](int x){ if (x%m==0 os << w << '\n');}
}
```

> The version using lambda is a clear winner. But if you really want a
>   name, you can just provide one ..

2. Capture template

> If you need to capture template argument, use ... For example:

```
template<typename... Var>
void algo(int s, Var... v){
  auto helper = [&s,&v...]{return s*(h1(v...)+h2(v...);)};
}
```

*h1 & h2 are simple examples functions*

Comment: Sorry... not to discourage you... but your code is wrong is so many way that I don't know how to start explaining it. Suggestion: try to understand variadic templates starting with very simple examples.

Comment: As the comment above mentioned, your use of `std::vector`, lambda capturing, variable declaration are all wrong.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, I added the two examples of Stroustrup in his book, In fact I am learning c++, So I try my way too.
I just wanted to concat its two examples to test myself.
Can you tell me what is really wrong ? I did not think I was so far from the true; and I sure want to understand my faults

Comment: Is somebody could help me a little?
@liliscent you said all is wrong, I really do not understand what you mean, you pseak about the pack parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain what is wrong in your code, but to be truly understood, you need to read [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

- `std::vector` is a homogeneous container, all its elements have only one same type. This `vector<vectType...>` is pointless. For example, `std::vector<int>` has all `int` elements; there is **no** such a thing `std::vector<int, double, short>`. Thus if you want to print the `typeid` for some different types, your approach is wrong from the beginning.
- In your own code `[&vectType...]`, those `vectType` are **types**, that's also pointless. In your quoted code `[&s,&v...]`, those `v` are **variables**, thus correct.
- Such `vectType... v;` declaration is invented by yourself, it's not C++.

The following is a simple example in `C++14` if you want to print variables' `typeid` in a generic way:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class... Args>
void print_all_typeid(Args const &...args)
{
    auto dumb = [] (auto... x) {};
    auto printer = [] (auto const &x) {
        std::cout << typeid(x).name() << "\n";
        return true;
    };

    dumb(printer(args)...);
}

int main() {
    print_all_typeid(std::cin, 12, std::cout, 1L, 2.0, 3.f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advices, as said in my post I am reading the "c++ programming langage" from Stroustrup. So I think it's a good book (1300 pages ouch)
I am not a beginner developper, the book is very good, I read It from start to end but sometimes there are things (like variadic template) I do not know that are juste showed before explained 300 pages latter; I think that is my misunderstand came from that fact.